# AWS API Gateway mapping json and pdf

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have my API Gateway set up with `application/json` Content-Type mapped to

```
{
    "param1": "$input.params('param1')"
}
```

and `application/pdf` mapped to

```
{
    "content": "$input.body"
}
```

Both of these work on their own when I use postman and specify the Content-Type as one or the other. 
But, **I want to be able to make a request that can take both pdf binary data along with some parameters from JSON using one call and use both in lambda**.

I've tried adding both of these in a content-type and setting the template as

```
{
    "content": "$input.body",
    "param1": "$input.params('param1')"
}
```

But this returns back an error when I call it with the params and the pdf:
`"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n`

*The "param1" is a query string parameter I have added.*

Comment: Have you tried encoding the body content, `"content": $util.base64Encode($input.body)"`?

Comment: I did now! So making another template as `application/pdfjson` and setting the content as that and the "param1" as normal seems to work.

Comment: Good to hear it works.